# Bit Setting in 32bit register

Tags: c++, bit

I have made this function to set bits in a register:

```
void setBitsInRange( const uint32_t offset, const uint8_t fromBit, const uint8_t numOfBits,  uint32_t val  )
{
    uint32_t regVal = readRegister( offset );
    uint32_t mask = (( 1 << ( fromBit + numOfBits)) - ( 1 << fromBit));
    aValueToSet = val << fromBit;
    uint32_t result = ( regVal & ~mask) | ( val & mask );
    writeRegister( offset, result );
}
```

This works for all bits except for when I need to change all 32 bits.  Is there a way to do this using the given API?

Here is an example

```
writeRegister(registerOffset,0x0);
setBitsInRange(registerOffset,0,32, 0xFFFFFFFF );
CHECK_EQUAL(0xFFFFFFFF, readRegister(registerOffset));  //FAIL


writeRegister(registerOffset,0x0);
setBitsInRange(registerOffset,0,31, 0x7FFFFFFF );
CHECK_EQUAL(0x7FFFFFFF, readRegister(registerOffset));

writeRegister(registerOffset,0x0);
setBitsInRange(registerOffset,16,16,0xAAAA);
readBack = readRegister(registerOffset);
CHECK_EQUAL(0xAAAA0000, readBack);
```

Comment: You do remember that bits are, like array indexes, zero-based?

Comment: Where does `aValueToSet` come from?

Comment: And exactly what happens when you try to use `fromBit=0` and `numOfBits=32`?

Comment: @Mats Peterson, it does not work, I know it goes 0-31 hence my question?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I now changed that to val

Comment: But exactly what "doesn't work"? Ideally, show us some real code that shows the problem.

Comment: flicking all 32bits does not work.  I will add an example

Comment: Could you remove the `bitset` tag? It has nothing to do with `std::bitset`

Comment: You could try: `if (fromBit + numOfBits == 32) mask = 0xFFFFFFFF - (1 << fromBit - 1) else mask = ...` (as before)

Comment: Great, but that's not a COMPLETE example that one of us can try, is it?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Obviously `1 << ( fromBit + numOfBits)` gives 0 when 1 is left-shifted by 32 (which can be implied from the description of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)((( 1LL << ( fromBit + numOfBits)) - ( 1 << fromBit)))`?

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes, and that should compensate by subtracting 1? Although I expect the problem is actually the opposite, that the mask becomes zero because `1 << (32)` is the same as `1 << (32  & 31)` == `1 << 0`, and then `1 << 0` + `1 << 0` = `1 << 1`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I haven't really verified that OP's solution works for all inputs except `0,32` (I just took OP's word for it). So assuming it's correct, wouldn't it solve the problem if you converted to 64-bits and then back to 32-bits?

Comment: Yes, but I want the OP to actually debug the problem - I think you are right, but learning debugging skills, learning to post a complete example, describe exactly what the problem is, etc, are good skill - according to the principle of "give a man a fish, feed him for a day, teach a man to fish, feed him for life"

Comment: @barakmanos  Your solution above works.  I tried converting to 64bit originally before posting but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for every input except `fromBit == 0 && numOfBits == 32`, then this should fix it:

```
uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)(((1LL << (fromBit + numOfBits)) - (1 << fromBit)))
```

Comment: @Mats Petersson: So I ended up giving the man (or woman) a fish. Not exactly the kind of fishing lesson that you recommended, but I think he (or she) got part of it from the comment thread above...

Comment: I learnt my lesson anyhow.  I knew that 64bit was a solution before posting but I did not use LL and so it did not work.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1876942: It should also work with `(uint64_t)1` instead of `1LL`. My guess is that you converted only the `1 << (fromBit + numOfBits)` part back to `uint32_t` (instead of the whole expression). In any case, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't work for any 32 bit shift. `uint32_t(1) << 32` is just undefined.

However, since you later do `- 1 << (fromBit)`, and unisgned arithmetic is modular, it doesn't matter whether you do `uint32_t(1ULL << 32 - 256)` or `0UL - 256UL`. In both cases the result is ~255UL, but in the latter it's just a 32 bit operation.

So you basically need to prefix `(fromBit + numOfBits == 32) ? 0 :`

Comment: See Barak Manos' solution.  It solves all 32bit shifts.